# Can abc.example.com read cookie value of xyz.example.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-elb

I have 2 node.js behind `AWS's ELB` with`sticky session`(domain address :`xyz.example.com`)

`AWS's ELB` sends a cookie for stick session thing on 1'st request.

I have a website hosted on `abc.example.com` and the `ELB` has domain address `xyz.example.com`.

Will the value of cookie sent by `AWS's ELB` be accessed by my site which is hosted on `abc.example.com`? Both `abc.example.com` and `xyz.example.com` are sub domain of `example.com`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) might help you get started

Comment: The cookie is sen't by **AWS**. I'm not setting it. So I can't do `.example.com` in the cokkie.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the initial comment, you can actually have control over the cookie by using an Application-Controlled cookie: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html#enable-sticky-sessions-application

This way you might be able to set hostOnly as false.
Hope it helps!